# Jenkins api not working - "Empty reply from server"

Tags: linux, jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson, continuous-deployment

I am trying to use jenkins api on localhost, but the jenkins server is sending "Empty reply from server". Any idea what's wrong ?

```
curl http://localhost:8080/job/test/lastBuild/api/json?token=testing  -v

* About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /job/test/lastBuild/api/json?token=testing HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.24.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.24.0 NSS/3.13.5.0 zlib/1.2.5     libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.2.2
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> 
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
* Closing connection #0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason, httpport was set to "-1" because of which jenkins was sending an empty reply.

Before -

```
JENKINS_ARGS="--httpPort=-1"
```

After -

```
JENKINS_ARGS="--httpPort=65530"
```

Comment: According to [the Jenkins docs](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins), httpPort=-1 means that HTTP is disabled (only HTTPS access is permitted).  If there was a reason for that, then your change is not ideal, and the correct change would be to make your request use https instead of http.